# Where to find the WKT of a particular co-ordinate system

Tags: coordinate-system, mapping, well-known-text, nettopologysuite

I'm using ProjNet in my C# application for coordinate conversion that requires WKT of source and target co-ordinate systems. I have googled but didn't find the WKT of MGA2020 Zone 46 [EPSG 7846], MGA2020 Zone 47 [EPSG 7847], MGA2020 Zone 59 [EPSG 7859]. Where can I get the list of WKT-CRS?

Comment: Please add some sites that you have found so far, maybe we can show you where from the sites you can find the information.

Comment: I googled just "EPSG 7846" and the first three results had WKT one link away (though one was awash in advertising and mostly useless)

Comment: epsg.io is what I use

Comment: `https://epsg.org/crs/wkt/id/7846` `https://epsg.org/crs/wkt/id/7847` `https://epsg.org/crs/wkt/id/7859`

Answer (score 4):

If the [map grid 2020 of australia is addressed](https://www.ga.gov.au/scientific-topics/positioning-navigation/geodesy/datums-projections/grid2020)

```
Parameter   Value:
Longitude of initial central meridian (Zone 1) = 177 degrees west longitude
Zone width           =  6 degrees
Central scale factor =  0.9996
False Easting        =  500,000 m
False Northing (in the southern hemisphere) = 10,000,000 m
```

And have a look at the proposed [WKT2 String design](http://docs.opengeospatial.org/is/18-010r7/18-010r7.html).

As commented above by @Vince ESPG numbers are two clicks away from Google.
[GDA2020 / MGA zone 59](http://epsg.io/7859).

You can find more detailed info's in [GDA2020 Technical Manual Version 1.1.1 Doc](https://www.icsm.gov.au/sites/default/files/GDA2020TechnicalManualV1.1.1.pdf) section *"1.6 Map Grid of Australia 2020 (MGA2020)"*.

Answer (score 2):

Try [epsg.io](http://epsg.io/) or [epsg.org](https://epsg.org/home.html). Should have everything you need.

Comment: epsg.org is the official EPSG registry, not epsg.io